# how to raise a method of user control from window by right-click?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want when Right-Click in the MainWindow, the ToggleIsCollapsed() method in MenuUserControl raise. I want use this as shortcut key for click on the button in MenuUserControl.

I have a user control like this:

```
public partial class MenuUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MenuUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly RoutedEvent ClickEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Click", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MenuUserControl));

    public event RoutedEventHandler Click
    {
        add { AddHandler(ClickEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(ClickEvent, value); }
    }

    void RaiseClickEvent()
    {
        RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(ClickEvent);
        RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
    }

    public bool IsCollapsed
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCollapsedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsCollapsedProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsCollapsed.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static DependencyProperty IsCollapsedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsCollapsed", typeof(bool), typeof(MenuUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public void ToggleIsCollapsed()
    {
        IsCollapsed = !IsCollapsed;
    }

    private void CollapseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseClickEvent();
    }
}
```

and a MainWindow like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : WindowBase
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddHandler(MenuUserControl.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(Click));
    }

    private void Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       // MenuUserControl.ToggleIsCollapsed();
    }

    private void WindowBase_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

do you help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`MouseRightButtonDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouserightbuttondown(v=vs.110).aspx) event to catch a mouse right click.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.MouseRightButtonDown += MainWindow_MouseRightButtonDown;
}

private void MainWindow_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MenuUserControl.ToggleIsCollapsed();
}

public partial class MenuUserControl
{
    public static void ToggleIsCollapsed()
    {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

The error you described in the comment happens because you're trying to call a non-static method (`IsCollapsed`) from a static method (`ToggleIsCollapsed`). You have two options:

Either make `IsCollapsed` static:

```
public static bool IsCollapsed
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCollapsedProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsCollapsedProperty, value); }
}
```

Or make `ToggleIsCollapsed` non-static:

```
public void ToggleIsCollapsed()
{
    // do your stuff
}
```

Note that if you make `ToggleIsCollapsed` non-static, you have to create a new instance of your `MenuUserControl` class. Otherwise you'll get the same error as before:

```
private void MainWindow_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // new instance of class
    MenuUserControl usrCtrl = new MenuUserControl();
    usrCtrl.ToggleIsCollapsed();
}
```

Comment: if I declare ToggleIsCollapsed() as static the IsCollapsed property give me this error: " An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property MenuUserControl.IsCollapsed" and I can't declare IsCollapsed property  as static for it's dependency property.

Comment: if I declare IsCollapsed property as static, GetValue(IsCollapsedProperty) and SetValue(IsCollapsedProperty, value) give me this error: " An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property DependencyObject.GetValue(DependencyProperty)" note that my dependencyProperty is static!

Comment: for second solution, you can't create an object of user control, because if you create another object of user control ,changes don't appear in UI. and It is act independently object.

Comment: This happens because `GetValue` and `SetValue` are non-static objects. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.getvalue?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I know that. but I don't know how to fix it! :(

Comment: Just create a new instance of `DependencyObject` to call `GetValue` and `SetValue` method.

Comment: Like `DependencyObject obj = new DependencyObject(); obj.GetValue()`